# DbDataConttoller UpdateEntity throws an exception

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4.1, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm experimenting with VS 2011 Beta and EF and I'm having trouble with UpdateEntity, but InsertEntity and DeleteEntity works fine.

The problem is that when I call UpdateEntity I get an "object reference not set to an instace of an object" exception.

Seems to happen with all the models in my project.

To try to isolate the problem, I created a really simple DTO class with basic properties, but I get the same error when I try to call UpdateEntity on that object.  Here's my code:

The Test DTO:

```
    [Table("Test")]
public class Test
{
    [Key, Column]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string TestMember { get; set; }
}
```

I've got a DbDataController with the following methods:

```
    public void InsertTest(Test entity)
    {
        InsertEntity(entity);
    }

    public void UpdateTest(Test entity)
    {
        UpdateEntity(entity);
    }

    public void DeleteTest(Test entity)
    {
        DeleteEntity(entity);
    }
```

Finally, I've defined this Test object in my DbContext class:

```
public DbSet<Test> Test { get; set; }
```

Of course I've got a table called Test in my database, this is the create script for the table:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TestMember] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Icelandic_CI_AS NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I can successfully insert new test objects to the database:

```
            using (DataController dataSource = new DataController())
        {
            Test test = new Test();
            test.Id = 1;
            test.TestMember = "test2";
            dataSource.InsertTest(test);
            dataSource.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I can then easily delete it from the database:

```
            using (DataController dataSource = new DataController())
        {
            Test test = new Test();
            test.Id = 1;
            test.TestMember = "test2";
            dataSource.DeleteTest(test);
            dataSource.SaveChanges();
        }
```

But if I try to do this:

```
            using (DataController dataSource = new DataController())
        {
            Test test = new Test();
            test.Id = 1;
            test.TestMember = "UpdatedTest";
            dataSource.UpdateTest(test);
            dataSource.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I get a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception at this line here:

**UpdateEntity(entity);**

inside the UpdateTest method in the DataController.

There is no InnerException and the stack trace is not exactly helpful:

> at System.Web.Http.Data.EntityFramework.DbDataController`1.UpdateEntity(Object entity)
>      at Hot.Web.Controllers.DataController.UpdateTest(Test entity) in c:\......\DataController.cs:line 48
>      at Hot.Web.Controllers.UserManagementController.EditProfile() in c:\.......\UserManagementController.cs:line 223
>      at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass42.b*_41()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c_*DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c*_DisplayClass37.<>c_*DisplayClass39.b*_33()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass4f.b*_49()

Anyone got any clue what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to query for the entity and then update that retrieved entity using your dbcontroller

```
using (DataController dataSource = new DataController()) {
        Test test = dataSource.getById(1); //Use whatever query method you need to here
        test.TestMember = "UpdatedTest";
        dataSource.UpdateTest(test);
        dataSource.SaveChanges();
    }
```